# ¿modificar la key de una tabla de hash en c++?

Tags: c++, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, c++11

quisiera modificar la key por una key nueva con mi algoritmo implementado ya trate de hacerlo pero solamente se ve afectado en el ultimo elemento no en los demas. Primero hize algo como esto que si sale si pongo un condicional antes de modificar la key este fue un ejemplo que hice en el cual me fui basando y si funciona bien

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string> mymap;

    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(1, "A1"));
    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(2, "A2"));
    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(3, "C1"));
    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(4, "C2"));
    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(5, "B1"));
    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(6, "B2"));
    mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(7, "B3"));

    cout << "antes de la modificacion tenemos" << endl;
    for (auto i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); i++) {
        cout << i->first << "  " << i->second << endl;
    }
    cout << "despues de la modificacion tenemos" << endl;
    int cuenta = 8;
    string cuenta2 = "hola";
    int N = mymap.size();
    int j = N;
    for (auto i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); i++) {
        auto it = mymap.find(i->first);
        while (it != mymap.end()) {
            unsigned int key = it->first;
            std::string val = it->second;
            int j = key;
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                key = key + 10;
            }
            //key = key + 10;

            //std::string val = it->second;
            //val = 'X' + val;
            //val = cuenta2;

            it = mymap.erase(it);
            mymap.insert(std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(key, val));
        }
    } //modifico todo la tabla

    for (auto i = mymap.begin(); i != mymap.end(); i++) {
        cout << i->first << "  " << i->second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora que quiero hacer esto mismo con mi algoritmo implementado para modificar la key si funciona pero para el ultimo elemento de la key. Mi algoritmo que estoy haciendo es de entrada metes N cadenas, despues te pregunta cuantos eventos quieres realizar por ultimo introduces dos caracteres si esos dos caracteres existen en las cadenas de entrada basicamente las intercambias y ya es todo por ejemplo esto es lo que espero en mi algorimo pero solamente lo hace para el ultimo elemento que se almacena en la tabla de hash:

```
entrada
2
mariano
mariana
2
C m a
C i o
salida 
amrimno
amrimnm
amromni
amromnm
```

Este es mi codigo fuente del algoritmo que quiero lograr para hacer esto del intercambio de caracteres sobre las cadenas

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int busquedaBinCadena(string cad, string caracter, int lon);

int main()
{
    cout << "Cuantos nombres deseas ingresar" << endl;
    unordered_map<string, int> tabla; //el primer parametro es la key
    // unordered_map<int, string> tabla; //el primer parametro es la key
    string cadena; //segundo parametro el valor
    int T;
    cin >> T; //leemos cuantos nombres se quieren introducir
    int indice = 1;
    while (T--) { //vemos cuantos nombres se quieren introducir
        cin >> cadena; //leemos una cadena con longitud la que sea
        tabla.insert({ cadena, indice }); //insertamos la cadena
        indice++; //con su respectivo indice que le corresponde
    } //fin del while
    char cadena2[10];
    char a;
    int b;
    cout << "cuantos eventos quieres hacer" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    while (b--) {
        scanf("%s %[^\n]", &a, &cadena2);
        if (a == 'C') {
            string carac1, carac2;
            carac1 = cadena2[0]; //primer caracter
            carac2 = cadena2[2]; //segundo caracter
            //copiamos el contenido de nuestra cadenas en una cadena auxiliar
            string aux;
            for (auto i = tabla.begin(); i != tabla.end(); i++) {
                auto it = tabla.find(i->first);
                while (it != tabla.end()) {

                    string key = it->first;
                    int val = i->second;

                    aux = i->first;
                    sort(aux.begin(), aux.end()); //ordenamos la cadena aux
                    int longitudAux = aux.size();
                    //buscamos tanto para el caracter 1 como el segundo
                    //si esta en la cadena aux
                    int result = busquedaBinCadena(aux, carac1, longitudAux);
                    int result2 = busquedaBinCadena(aux, carac2, longitudAux);
                    string cambioStr;
                    cambioStr = i->first;
                    int bandera;
                    if (result != -1 || result2 != -1) { //si encontro algun caracter en la cadena aux

                        //ahora si hacemos el cambio pertinente en la cadena de la tabla de hash
                        for (int j = 0; j < cambioStr.size(); j++) { //iteramos sobre la cadena
                            //hacemos los cambios que nos pide el ejercicio para cada una de las cadenas
                            //donde existan el caracter que metio el usuario para cada una de las cadenas entrantes
                            if (cambioStr[j] == carac1[0]) {
                                cambioStr[j] = carac2[0];
                            } //fin if
                            else {
                                if (cambioStr[j] == carac2[0]) {
                                    cambioStr[j] = carac1[0];
                                } //fin if
                            } //fin else
                        } //fin del for para el cambioStr
                        cout << cambioStr << endl;
                        key = cambioStr;
                    } //fin del if para encontrar un caracter en la cadena

                    it = tabla.erase(it);
                    tabla.insert(std::unordered_map<string, int>::value_type(key, val));

                } //fin del while para actualizar la tabla*/
            } //fin del for para la tabla donde iteramos
            cout << "La tabla actualizada tenemos" << endl;
            for (auto i = tabla.begin(); i != tabla.end(); i++) {
                cout << i->first << "  " << i->second << endl;
            }
        } //fin del if ext
    } //fin del while
    return 0;
}

//busqueda binaria para un caracter en una cadena usando los tipos string de c++
int busquedaBinCadena(string cad, string caracter, int lon)
{
    int izquierda = 0, derecha = lon - 1;
    string carac;
    carac = caracter;
    while (izquierda <= derecha) {
        int indiceDeLaMitad = floor((izquierda + derecha) / 2);

        string elementoDeLaMitad; //no podemos asignar un string con un caracter
        elementoDeLaMitad = cad[indiceDeLaMitad];

        int resultadoDeLaComparacion = carac.compare(elementoDeLaMitad);
        // Si son iguales hemos encontrado el elemento
        if (resultadoDeLaComparacion == 0)
            return indiceDeLaMitad;

        // Si no, vemos en cuál mitad podría estar

        // ¿A la izquierda?
        if (resultadoDeLaComparacion < 0) {
            derecha = indiceDeLaMitad - 1;
        }
        else {
            // A la derecha
            izquierda = indiceDeLaMitad + 1;
        }
    }
    // Si termina el ciclo y no encontramos nada, regresamos -1
    return -1;
}
```

Ya lo intente hacer pero no mas no me sale agradeciría su ayuda.

Comment: ¿ Podrías explicar *mas mejor* tu problema ? He intentado compilar tu ejemplo (poniendo **todos** los `#include` que te faltan, que no son pocos), y lo único que he conseguido es un bucle infinito con la frase `"La tabla actualizada tenemos"`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/z6flRUz1pIDGUywX

Comment: el codigo que puse es el que estoy compilando los includes funciona muy bien con uno que es bits/stdc++ porque estoy utilizando la plantila de STL lo corro en linux y funciona bien

Comment: `bits/stdc++` **no** pertenece al estandar (es propio de `gcc`), y no se puede usar si pretendes que tu código sea portable. Y te puse el link a `wandbox`, que compila y corre tu programa bajo linux ... y entra en bucle sin fin. Puedes comprobarlo, no tienes mas que ir al enlace.

Answer (score 2):

Las claves de un mapa **no deben modificarse** bajo ningún concepto. Esto es así porque los mapas no disponen de mecanismos que permitan su reorganización cuando cambian los valores que almacenan sin previo aviso.

Lo que tienes que hacer es sacar el valor del mapa, modificarlo e insertarlo de nuevo.

Por otro lado veo que las claves se están modificando sin aplicar cambios al valor original. Has de saber que las claves de los mapas de la STL se calculan usando la función `std::hash`... y esa función únicamente va a tener en cuenta el valor del elemento que se inserta en el mapa, es decir, no se le pueden aplicar **offset** posteriores.

Tendrás que replantear tu algoritmo.

Si fueses capaz de modificar la clave de un elemento del mapa se producirían un comportamiento errático del mapa ya que los mapas se organizan según las claves para encontrar los elementos rápidamente. Modificar una clave haría que la misma quedase encuadrada en un grupo que no le corresponde, lo que te imposibilitaría localizar al elemento por su clave (ni por la antigua, que ya no se encontraría en el mapa, ni por la nueva, que estará en un lugar incorrecto).